# JSF PrimeFaces: Issue with p:selectOneMenu setting enum to null on form submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm encountering an issue with JSF and PrimeFaces where my p:selectOneMenu for an enum type is not maintaining its selected value upon form submission. Here's the relevant part of my XHTML file:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="debitDialog" modal="true" header="Billing Details" id="debitDialog">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{userDetailBillingController.eventSelected}">
        <h:panelGrid id="billingGrid" columns="2">
            <!-- Other components -->
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{userDetailBillingController.selectedDebitStatus}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{userDetailBillingController.availableDebitStatuses}"
                           var="status"
                           itemLabel="#{status}"
                           itemValue="#{status}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userDetailBillingController.changeDebitStatus()}"
                         oncomplete="PF('debitDialog').hide()" update=":userBillingForm"/>
    </ui:fragment>
</p:dialog>
```

Here's the relevant part of my backing bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class UserDetailBillingController implements Serializable {
    // Fields, constructors, other methods...

    private DebitStatus selectedDebitStatus;

    public DebitStatus getSelectedDebitStatus() {
        return selectedDebitStatus;
    }

    public void setSelectedDebitStatus(DebitStatus debitStatus) {
        this.selectedDebitStatus = debitStatus;
    }

    public void changeDebitStatus() {
        selectedBilling.setDebitStatus(selectedDebitStatus);
        billingService.saveBilling(selectedBilling);
        if (selectedDebitStatus.equals(DebitStatus.FAILED))
            premiumMembershipService.revokePremiumMembership(currentUser.getUsername());
        userService.saveUser(currentUser);
    }
}
```

Initially, the selectedDebitStatus is set properly through the getter method. However, when I choose a different option from the dropdown and click the "Save" button, the setSelectedDebitStatus method is called with a null value.

I've already tried adding an <p:ajax> listener to the p:selectOneMenu, but the value is still set to null upon submission. DebitStatus is an enum class.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the selected enum value is submitted correctly?
I even tried working with Strings instead of the enum directly and translating it in the bean. No matter what I try it always sets selectedDebitStatus to null.I've already tried adding an <p:ajax> listener to the p:selectOneMenu, but the value is still set to null upon submission. DebitStatus is an enum class.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the selected enum value is submitted correctly?

Comment: what version of JSF?  If JSF 2.3 it supports enums natively and you can just do this `<f:selectItems value="#{userDetailBillingController.availableDebitStatuses}" />`  You can read more about it here: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter